# Why are backslashes doubled in output of file paths?

Tags: python, windows

I have a problem with this script. In the output it doubles `\\`.

```
import os
import time
import shutil

login = os.getlogin()

print(login)
while True:
    filepath = input()
    if filepath == 'end':
        break
    elif filepath[0:4] == 'copy': #im start command with 'copy' to copy file like 'copy C:\\Users...'
        dirlist = os.listdir(filepath[5::])
        print('Type dir to copied file')
        codir = input('copy dir is..\n')
        shutil.copy(filepath[5::], codir)
    elif filepath[0:6] == 'search': #im start command with 'search' to copy file like 'search C:\\Users...'
        print(filepath[6:-1])
        dirlist = os.listdir(filepath[6::])
        searchfile = input('file you want to search\n')
        if searchfile in dirlist:
            print("True")
    else:
        dirlist = os.listdir(filepath) # if it has no command, it's just show dir list
        print(dirlist)
print('Script end!')
```

Output:

```
$ Tester.py

 Artem

 С:\\\Users

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Artem\Desktop\Tester.py", line 24, in <module>

 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'С:\\\\Users'
                                ^System can't reach this way:'C:\\\\Users'
```

Why does it double `\\`?

Comment: Are you asking (1) why it shows ```\\``` instead of ```\``` or (2) why it shows ```\\\\``` instead of ```\\```?

Comment: both problems, it shows ```\\``` instead of ```\``` and ```\\\\``` instead of ```\\```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago, Microsoft chose to use the backslash `\` as a separator, perhaps through naivete (though it seems like an intentional choice to thwart compatibility), while it's been an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) for an eternity (indicating a special character like `\n` for a newline or `\t` for a tab) and the rest of the sane world uses `/` for this amongst many reasons.

`\\` is displaying an escaped backslash `\` for compatibility

The system has trouble displaying this, but you can use `/` and it'll work fine in most, if not all, cases

You may also find [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) does everything you need for all your pathing more nicely than pure string handling!